# click data by position on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to click data randomly in same div name. data pick  by data-position in same div button

**html**

```
<div class="wrap">
<button data-position="1" class="block-shadow play">
<div class=""></div>
</button>
<button data-position="2" class="block-shadow play">
<div class=""></div>
</button>
<button data-position="3" class="block-shadow play">
<div class=""></div>
</button>
<button data-position="4" class="block-shadow play">
<div class=""></div>
</button>
<button data-position="5" class="block-shadow play">
<div class=""></div>
</button>

</div>
```

** jquery**

```
window.setInterval(function() {
 var tile1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    //search_last_bomb();
    $('#block-shadow play').first().find('[data-position=' + tile1 + ']').click();
//document.getElementsByClassName("fal fa-sync")[0].click();
}, 200);
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the real question? how to generate a random number in a limited range?

Answer (score 0):

Just select directly the element that you want to click

```js
setInterval(function() {
  let tile1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  $(`[data-position=${tile1}]`).click();
}, 200);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button data-position="1" class="block-shadow play">
  <div class=""></div>
  </button>
  <button data-position="2" class="block-shadow play">
  <div class=""></div>
  </button>
  <button data-position="3" class="block-shadow play">
  <div class=""></div>
  </button>
  <button data-position="4" class="block-shadow play">
  <div class=""></div>
  </button>
  <button data-position="5" class="block-shadow play">
  <div class=""></div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).